# Use the correct values/strings.xml of a library project from within the library project

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources, library-project

I'm developing an Android application which uses a library project that contains general methods which are being used by several of my applications in the workspace.

In the library project I have a class with a method that shows alert dialogs and some toast messages.

What I am trying to do is use **the library's** "res/values/strings.xml" values for those alert dialogs and toast messages.
The point is that I ofcourse want the values to be taken are the relevant string values according to the current user's language.
This way, whenever I'll use those methods within the library from **other applications** I won't have to re-translate the strings for each application within the application's "values/strings.xml".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the beauty of using libraries: whatever strings are defined in the application override the ones in the library. If I understand your question correctly, you shouldn't have to do anything: just make sure keep the string names the same.

See this quote from the [documentation on libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html):

> Since the tools merge the resources of a library project with those of
>   a dependent application project, a given resource ID might be defined
>   in both projects. In this case, the tools select the resource from the
>   application, or the library with highest priority, and discard the
>   other resource. As you develop your applications, be aware that common
>   resource IDs are likely to be defined in more than one project and
>   will be merged, with the resource from the application or
>   highest-priority library taking precedence.

Comment: Apparently what I was looking for is the "getString" method which I finnaly was able to use only with the **active Activity's context** through a parameter, like that: `theActivityContext.getString(R.string.Translated_String)`